# Can I set an identifying property for a process I start from my program?

Tags: vb.net, process

Is it possible to set some kind of identifier in a new System.Diagnostics.Process or ProcessStartInfo property that I start from my program so I can find that same process later from a different instance of my program?

I am recording a few (less than 4) RTSP streams using FFMPEG by creating a new Process for each stream and saving the raw video file to disk.  A separate program is also running an instance of FFMPEG to convert and compress the raw videos to MP4. If my program quits unexpectedly, it leaves the FFMPEG streams still recording. I would like to kill the processes my program started without killing the conversion process that is running in the other program, so only qualifying processes by name isn't enough.

Comment: `Process.Start()` returns a Process object. You can store it and reference it later/somewhere else. Better check for null, before. Or subscribe to its `Exited` event, so you'll know if it's gone.

Comment: I would have to store that information externally because once my program exits, that Process object would be lost. I'm wondering if there is a property I can set in the process I start that will stay with that process if my program were to quit unexpectedly and I was not able to close the processes I started.

Comment: You can write the `ProcessId` to a temp file or to an app Setting or the Registry. When your app starts, you can check whether that Process (`Process.GetProcessById()`) exists and, if it does, it's the same `Process.ProcessName` you expect. You can then `Kill()` it or try to `.CloseMainWindow()`. Or use it.